Can't figure out multi-dimensional Perl hash references: Not a HASH reference
Yes, I've looked through many of the "not a HASH reference" articles, but none seem to address my issue. I have a multidimensional hash. Inside a for-loop where I'm a few levels down in my hash just working with the values of the last hash in the chain, I wanted to save typing by making a hash reference to this last hash.
This value exists:
$date2solveInfo{ $weekDate }{ $dow }{ secs } = 2272;

I assign my hash reference like so:
my $ref = \( %date2solveInfo{ $weekDate}->{ $dow});
The debugger is about to execute that line as shown below.

  DB<2> x %date2solveInfo  # showing what we're taking a reference to

0  '2020-09-07'
1  HASH(0x7faaec193f68)
   'Tue' => HASH(0x7faaec193f20)
      'secs' => 2272

  DB<3> s    # does the reference assignment above

  DB<3> x $ref  # showing the contents of $ref

0  REF(0x7faaea208ef8)
   -> HASH(0x7faaec193f20)
         'secs' => 2272

  DB<4> p $ref->{"secs"}  # try to deref the hash reference

Not a HASH reference at (eval 15)[/System/Library/Perl/5.30/perl5db.pl:738] line 2, <$fh> line 10.

It seems like the debugger is showing $ref is a reference to hash, so I'm puzzled.

{ "secs} looks fishy. Do you use strict; and use warnings;? Can you please show a [mre] so that we can run it and get the same error?

$ref is not a hash reference (like { secs => 2272 }), but a reference to a hash reference (like \{ secs => 2272 }. Hence one need to dereference it again:
  DB<5> p ${$ref}->{"secs"}
2272

To access a simple hash reference you would have to use
my $ref = $date2solveInfo{ $weekDate}->{ $dow};

Instead you've added another layer of reference by using
 # replacing `%` with `$` in `date2solveInfo`, as warnings suggest one should do
 my $ref = \( $date2solveInfo{ $weekDate}->{ $dow});


@TLP: I deliberatly changed it since perl clearly pointed out the wrong use in a warning ("%{...}  in scalar context better written as ${...}"), see also the comment before the code fragment. But yes, it resolves into the same.

$ref->$*->{"secs"} would be clearer than ${$ref}->{"secs"}

Re "To take a simple hash reference", That's not what that does at all.

@ikegami: right, it is not take a (new) reference but to access the existing one.

@SteffenUllrich Ah, I didn't see that comment before, my mistake.

Works perfectly! I removed the extra \.
my $ref = %date2solveInfo{ $weekDate}->{ $dow};

DB<2> x $ref
0  HASH(0x7f8f7e84a320)
   'secs' => 2272

DB<3> p $ref->{"secs"}
2272

DB<4> $ref->{"a"} = 16

DB<5> x $ref
0  HASH(0x7f8f7e84a320)
   'a' => 16
   'secs' => 2272

This allows me to create to key-values as I desire (dummy example with key “a” shown).
Thanks!!

As previously mentioned, %date2solveInfo{ $weekDate}->{ $dow} is wrong. The % should be a $.

The -> operator is actually not required in that statement. It is only needed when accessing a hash reference, and only the first time. E.g. in $ref->{foo}{bar} it is only used with the first reference. In the case of a hash you don't use them at all: $date{foo}{bar}. And whitespace is not necessary, and personally I find it ambiguous. So you can make it my $ref = $date2solveInfo{$weekDate}{$dow};. It feels like you make references harder than they are. :)
